# Repeatable read: the transaction may not be serializable with respect to other transactions

Tags: database

The text below is from 'Database System Concepts, Silberschatz. I can't understand the bolded part. How the transaction may not be serializable with respect to other transactions? And also how a transaction may find some of the data inserted by a committed transaction, but may not find other data inserted by the same transaction?

> Repeatable read allows only committed data to be read and further
> requires that, between two reads of a data item by a transaction, no
> other transaction is allowed to update it. However, the transaction
> may not be serializable with respect to other transactions. For
> instance, when it is searching for data satisfying some conditions, a
> transaction may find some of the data inserted by a committed
> transaction, but may not find other data inserted by the same
> transaction.

Comment: And the definition of serializable is what? And the definition of repeatble read is what? And those involve interpreting a transaction how? And say what about them? And where are you first stuck in this quote interpreting what it says about transactions? And what has your research shown that is relevant? Right now you are essentially asking us to rewrite a textbook from scratch with no idea what you do or don't understand or misunderstand.

Comment: You are jumping to (wrong) conclusions. I have neutrally posted questions in a form that is asking for the answers to be part of your post to help you get an answer to whatever your question would be if it were sufficiently focused. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]